# how to simulate the Johnson noise in ccoomputer?

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, noise

I am wondering how someone can simulate the Johnson noise in computer? I know it is random however I do not know what distribution it has. According to following link : its power can be calculated but how to actually generate the noise itself. Can anyone explain the steps and the parameters needed to generate and simulate the noise.

http://www.radio-electronics.com/info/rf-technology-design/noise/thermal-johnson-nyquist-basics-tutorial.php

Comment: See this answer: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/17494/how-to-simulate-awgn-in-communication-systems-for-specific-bandwidth?rq=1. (use randn in Matlab/Octave to generate a sequence from a normally distributed random variable)

Comment: i do it by yelling and ranting obscenities.  but since i got married 32 years ago, it's been renamed *"Bristow-Johnson noise"*