SNR gain in DFT processing for real-valued signals
I am trying to understand an apparent $3\,\text{dB}\,\mathrm{SNR}$ loss in a detection application, where the presence of a sinusoidal signal in noise is to be detected.
Continuous time signal model
The signal of interest is a sinusoid of amplitude $A$ with frequency $f_0$
$$
s(t) = A \cos(2 \pi f_0t) + n(t)
$$
where the noise $n(t)$ is modeled as additive Gaussian noise with power spectral density $N_0$, band limited by an ideal low pass filter $H(f)$ of bandwidth $f_s/2$ to yield the well known result for total noise power
$$
P_n = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{N_0}{2} \lvert H(f) \rvert^2 df = N_0 \frac{f_s}{2}.
$$
The $\mathrm{SNR}$ of the sinusoid is then simply
$$
\mathrm{SNR} = \frac{A^2}{2 P_n} = \frac{A^2}{N_0 f_s}
$$
which implies that for modeling purposes I may express the amplitude of the sinusoid in terms of its $\mathrm{SNR}$
$$
A = \sqrt{2P_n\mathrm{SNR}_\mathrm{in}} = \sqrt{N_0 f_s \mathrm{SNR}_\mathrm{in}}
$$
Discrete time model
In practice I am working with a discrete time signal which I want to express as
$$
s[n] = A\cos\left(2 \pi \frac{f_0}{f_s}n\right) + \nu[n]
$$
where $\nu$ are independent and identically distributed zero-mean Gaussian random samples
$$
\nu[n] \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0, \sigma^2\right).
$$
The noise samples are uncorrelated (and in the Gaussian case therefore independent) because of the periodic zeros in the filtered noise's autocorrelation function.
Similar to before, I would like to simplify the simulation so choose $\sigma^2 = 1$ and this results in $A = \sqrt{2\mathrm{SNR}_\mathrm{in}}$, so far so good.
DFT processing (SNR) gain
For a windowed DFT with window function $w$, the normalized processing gain in terms of SNR is given in [Har78] as
$$
\mathrm{PG} = \frac{\mathrm{SNR}_\mathrm{out}}{\mathrm{SNR}_\mathrm{in}}= \frac{\left(\sum_n w[n]\right)^2}{\sum_n w[n]^2}.
$$
Now I compute the DFT of the discrete time model signal $s[n]$
$$
S[k] = \frac{1}{\sum_n w[n]} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} w[n] s[n] \exp\left\{-j2\pi\frac{nk}{N}\right\}
$$
where the normalization term is there to ensure a DC gain of 1.
The plot below shows the average of $M = 1000$ realizations of $\rvert S[k] \lvert^2$ where $N = 256$, $f_0 = f_s/16$, unit noise variance in the time domain $\sigma^2=1$ and $A = \sqrt{2\mathrm{SNR}_\mathrm{in}} = \sqrt{2}$. A Hann window is chosen for $w$.
As expected for unit variance noise, the noise level after DFT computation is $-10\log_{10} \mathrm{PG} = -22.32\,\text{dB}$.
The signal level for each spectral line is only $-3\,\text{dB}$, which makes sense because of the Hermitian symmetry of the spectrum of a real valued signal, the total signal power is still $0\,\text{dB}$.
In my particular case this is a problem however, because I perform signal detection only on the first half of the DFT output, effectively incurring a $3\,\text{dB}$ loss in $\mathrm{SNR}_\mathrm{out}$.
Is there a way to avoid this? Is there a problem with my signal model that might explain this?
I suspect it might be related to the fact that I'm using a real-valued system and not I/Q demodulation?

References
[Har78] F. J. Harris, "On the use of windows for harmonic analysis with the discrete Fourier transform," in Proceedings of the IEEE, vol. 66, no. 1, pp. 51-83, Jan. 1978, doi: 10.1109/PROC.1978.10837

The 3 dB loss isn’t just due to the hermitian symmetry, at least it’s not the inherent reason for it. Think about the Euler identity of cosine and how it relates to -3 dB.

Well yes, $\cos x = \left(e^{jx} + e^{-jx}\right)/2$, the factor 1/2 accounting for the power being split up between the positive and negative frequency components.
Still, why does the same problem not affect the noise, i.e. why is the noise not also 3dB lower?

The noise is additive, so only the cosine is getting scaled by the $\frac{1}{2}$.

So then assuming I only use the first half of the spectrum for detection (for example using a CFAR detector) we agree that this effectively incurs a 3dB loss in SNR?

Yes, it's the cosine definition that incurs this loss.

The "Signal" consists of both peaks so the total power is the sum square of the two, thus -3 dB in each for a total of 0 dB.   The DFT is correlating to each component $e^{j\omega t}$ and cosine consists of both components as you wrote above.  And to your comment, the noise is indeed 3 dB lower than if you were to plot the one sided spectrum (what you have with both halves of the DFT is the two-sided spectrum).  So there is no loss in SNR.

(see this post where I demonstrate a one-sided vs two-sided spectrum where you can see the noise as well as signal is decreased by 3 dB in the two sided spectrum: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/88623/21048

I concur that effectively there is no SNR loss in theory because the signal consists of both halves. However, in practice I apply a detector in the frequency domain only to the first half of the DFT output. Therefore I see an apparent 3dB loss in SNR (because by using half of the DFT I'm also throwing away half of the signal).
I don't see how to fix this though, the one sided spectrum would shift everything up by 3dB, leaving SNR unchanged. Or should my noise variance really be 1/2 in the discrete case?
