Deriving the BER equations for BPSK; justification for noise variance of $\frac{N_0}{2}$
We model White Gaussian noise (having power $\sigma^2$) as a Gaussian process $n$, whereby for every interval $(t_0,~ t_0 + L)$ the integral $\int_{t_0}^{t_0 + L}n~dt$ is a Gaussian random variable with distribution $\mathcal N(0, L \sigma^2)$ representing the energy in the signal over the interval. For white noise, we may also assume that the resulting new variables for non-overlapping intervals are independent.
Letting $n$ be such a signal and $s_0 = - \sqrt{\frac{2~E_b}{T_b}}\cos(\omega t) $ be our BPSK signal over one bit, we take the sum through a matched filter to find
\begin{align*}
q &= \int_0^{T_b} (s_0(t) + n(t)) \cos(\omega t)~dt\\
&= -\sqrt{\frac{2~ E_b}{T_b}} \int_0^{T_b} \cos(\omega t)^2~dt + \int_0^{T_b} n(t) \cos(\omega t)~dt\\
&= -\sqrt{\frac{E_b~T_b}{2}} + X
\end{align*}
where we define a new random variable
$$X = \int_0^{T_b} n(t) \cos(\omega t)~dt$$
and our decision criterion is $q < 0$.
Assuming white noise, I can show that $X$ is Gaussian with distribution $\mathcal N \left (0 , \frac{1}{2} T_b \sigma^2 \right )$
It follows that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}~ \{ \text{Error}\} &= \mathbb{P}~ \{ q > 0 \}\\
&= \mathbb{P} \left \{ X > \sqrt{\frac{E_b~T_b}{2}} \right \}\\
&= Q \left ( \frac{\sqrt{\frac{E_b~T_b}{2}}}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} T_b \sigma^2}} \right )\\
&= Q \left ( \sqrt{\frac{E_b}{\sigma^2}}\right )
\end{align*}
From here I want to get to the expected form
$$\mathbb{P}~ \{ \text{Error}\} = Q \left ( \sqrt{\frac{2~E_b}{N_0}}\right )$$
which suggests that
$$\sigma^2 = \frac{N_0}{2}$$
This is indeed the assumption made here, here, here, here... all without justification for why this is taken to be the signal "variance".
But this $\frac{N_0}{2}$ is really only a tiny fraction of my signal power $\sigma^2$ (as defined in the beginning). Where does this assertion that $\sigma^2 = \frac{N_0}{2}$ come from? I would have thought that if we are to have a (single-sided) bandwidth of at least $\frac{1}{2~T_b}$, then we should lower-bound the resulting power (variance) by at least $\frac{N_0}{2~T_b} \leq \sigma^2$ (which is agreed with here).
In this case I would put
$$\mathbb{P}~ \{ \text{Error}\} = Q \left ( \sqrt{\frac{2~E_b~T_b}{N_0}}\right )$$
So why do we take the variance to be $\frac{N_0}{2}$?

Follow-up 1: Calculation of $\int_0^T n(t) \cos(\omega t)$
I will show here that this is a Gaussian RV with variance $\frac{1}{2} T \sigma^2$ when $\sigma^2$ is the variance of $n$. I use the two defining properties I am assuming of noise from the outset;

that $\int_0^T n~ dt$ is a Gaussian RV with distribution $\mathcal N(0, T \sigma^2)$
If intervals $I_1$ and $I_2$ are such that $I_1 \cap I_2 = \emptyset$ then $\text{Cov} \left ( \int_{I_1} n~dt,  \int_{I_2} n~dt\right ) = 0$

First, take $X = \lim_{K \rightarrow \infty} X_K$ where
\begin{align*}
X_K &= \sum_{k=1}^K \int_{\frac{(k-1)T}{K}}^{\frac{kT}{K}} n(t) \cos \left (\omega~ T~ \frac{k}{K} \right ) dt\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^K \cos \left (\omega~ T ~\frac{k}{K} \right ) \int_{\frac{(k-1)T}{K}}^{\frac{kT}{K}} n(t) dt\\
&=: \sum_{k=1}^K Y_k
\end{align*}
whereby
$$Y_k = \cos \left (\omega~ T ~\frac{k}{K} \right ) \int_{\frac{(k-1)T}{K}}^{\frac{kT}{K}} n(t) dt\\\\$$
Now I will use Lindeberg Central Limit Theorem via Feller's theorem to show convergence of the sequence of partial sums, to a Gaussian RV with distribution $\mathcal N(0, \frac{1}{2} T \sigma^2)$. I will adopt the following abuse of notation: for some $x$ being a variable with distribution $\mathcal N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, I will write $x \in \mathcal N(\mu, \sigma^2)$
So take
\begin{align*}
s_K^2 &= \sum_{k=1}^K \text{Var}(Y_k)\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^K \text{Var} \left (\cos \left (\omega~ T ~\frac{k}{K} \right ) \int_{\frac{(k-1)T}{K}}^{\frac{kT}{K}} n(t) dt \right )\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^K \cos \left (\omega~ T ~\frac{k}{K} \right )^2 \text{Var} \left ( \int_{\frac{(k-1)T}{K}}^{\frac{kT}{K}} n(t) dt \right )\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^K \cos \left (\omega~ T ~\frac{k}{K} \right )^2 \frac{T}{K} \sigma^2\\
&= \sigma^2 \sum_{k=1}^K \cos \left (\omega~ T ~\frac{k}{K} \right )^2 \frac{T}{K} \\
&\xrightarrow{K \rightarrow \infty} \sigma^2 \int_0^T \cos \left (\omega~ t \right )^2  dt\\
&= \sigma^2 \int_0^T \left (\frac{1}{2}  + \frac{1}{2} \cos \left (2 \omega~ t \right )  \right )dt\\
&\approx \sigma^2 \int_0^T \frac{1}{2} dt\\
&= \frac{1}{2} T \sigma^2
\end{align*}
The plan is to use Feller's conditions to show that Lindeberg's condition is satisfied, hence we shall have proven
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} T \sigma^2}} X
&= \lim_{K \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{s_K} \sum_{k=1}^K Y_k\\
& \in \mathcal N(0, 1)
\end{align*}
Feller's Condition 1
We require $\forall \epsilon > 0$, in the limit as $K \rightarrow \infty$, $\forall 1 \leq k \leq K$ that $\mathbb P \{|Y_k| > \epsilon~s_K\} = 0$.
Now (pretty much) by assumption, we have
$$Y_k \in \mathcal N\left (0, \frac{T}{K} \cos \left ( \omega~T~\frac{k}{K}\right )^2 \sigma^2 \right )$$
Let $\epsilon > 0$ and let $M \in \mathbb N$ be arbitrary. Then let $K > \max \{M, \left ( \frac{\sqrt{T}~M~\sigma}{\epsilon~s_M}\right ) ^2 \}$. Then $s_K \geq s_M$ and
\begin{align*}
\frac{\epsilon~ s_K}{\sqrt{\frac{T}{K}} \left \lvert \cos \left ( \omega T \frac{k}{K}  \right ) \right \rvert \sigma}
&\geq \frac{\sqrt{K}~\epsilon~s_M}{\sqrt{T}~\sigma}\\
&= M
\end{align*}
Interpret the above as saying, given $K$ large enough, we can make the fraction $\frac{\epsilon s_K}{\sqrt{\frac{T}{K}} \left \lvert \cos \left ( \omega~t~\frac{k}{K} \right ) \right \rvert \sigma}$ arbitrarily large.
Hence, taking $K$ as arbitrary and letting $1 \leq k \leq K$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P \{ \lvert Y_k \rvert > \epsilon~ s_K\}
&= Q \left ( \frac{\epsilon s_K}{\sqrt{\frac{T}{K}} \left \lvert \cos \left ( \omega~t~\frac{k}{K} \right ) \right \rvert \sigma} \right )\\
&\xrightarrow{K \rightarrow \infty} 0
\end{align*}
$\square$
Feller's Condition 2
We require that the sequence $K \mapsto \frac{X_K}{s_K}$ converges weakly to a standard normal distribution as $K \rightarrow \infty$. This will follow from the assumption of whiteness. Since each $\frac{X_K}{s_K}$ is a sum of zero mean Gaussians, it is a zero-mean Gaussian with variance
\begin{align*}
\text{Var} \left (\frac{X_K}{s_K} \right ) &= \frac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^K \text{Var}(Y_k)} \text{Var} \left ( \sum_{k=1}^K Y_k\right )\\
&=\frac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^K \text{Var}(Y_k)} \sum_{i, j=1}^K \mathbb E \left (  Y_i Y_j\right )\\
&=\frac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^K \text{Var}(Y_k)} \sum_{i, j=1}^K \text{Var}(Y_i) \delta_{i, j}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^K \text{Var}(Y_k)} \sum_{k=1}^K \text{Var}(Y_k)\\
&= 1
\end{align*}
Thus the sequence $K \mapsto \frac{S_K}{s_K}$ has a constant distribution, so the distribution does converge weakly to $\mathcal N(0, 1)$.
$\square$

You claim "Assuming white noise, I can show that $X$ is Gaussian with distribution $\mathcal N \left (0 , \frac{1}{2} T_b \sigma^2 \right ).$" Could you edit your question to include the details of this calculation? I am curious to learn how you managed to get $\sigma^2$ in there, because when I tried to replicate the calculations (cf. my answer below), I got $0$ as the result, since $E[N(t)N(s)]=0$.

I'm not really sure where your $E[N(t) N(s)] = 0$ is coming from? I've added my derivation as requested.

Your error is in the assumption $\int_0^T n(t) ,\mathrm dt = T\sigma^2$. The integral of white noise is not a constant; it is a random variable. If the noise is Gaussian white noise, then $\int_0^T n(t) ,\mathrm dt$ is a zero-mean Gaussian random variable. I haven't read the rest of your derivation very carefully, but it is totally unnecessary to invoke the CLT here.

"I'm not really sure where your $[()()]=0$ is coming from?"  I have combined the expectation of the product to two integrals into a double integral of the product of the integrands and then taken the expectation inside the integral (which is perfectly legal to do, by the way). $N(t)$ and $N(s)$ are independent zero-mean random variables except when $t=s$  and so $E[N(t)N(s)]=0$ except when $t=s$ when it has value $\sigma^2$ according to you. So, since the integrant has value $0$ almost everywhere in the square of side $T$, the integral is $0$. You need that Dirac delta in there!

Sorry that was a typo. I did actually mean that, and used it properly throughout the rest. The assumption is that it will be zero mean RV with variance equal to $T \sigma^2$, as taken from the linked Wikipedia article. I fixed that mistake in the above now.

I think the model of white noise I am using assumes that we can't actually know the intantaneous value of $n(t)$ which is left undefined; only its integral is defined. For non-overlapping intervals we do have their covariance zero. But then that is assumed in any definition of white noise?
Approximating the variable by simple functions, the integrals in question are non-zero on sets of non-zero measure. Then (I think) we can put it all back together as I've done.

Ok, so now include a derivation of how you determined what you assumed: that $\int_0^T N(t) dt$ has variance $T\sigma^2$. You once again need a double integral over the square of side $T$ (looks just like what I wrote except for the cosine terms) and once again, since distinct $N(t)$ and $N(s)$ are uncorrelated while $E[(N(t))^2]=\sigma^2$, we get to the same problem.  You can't get to variance $T\sigma^2$ without using a Dirac delta.  I have added some stuff at the end of my answer.

The OP's model of white noise as a process with finite power is where the problem is.
The standard model of continuous-time white noise that is used in communications and signal processing has infinite total power but finite power spectral density. To put it blasphemously, white noise is like God -- infinitely powerful and present everywhere regardless of whether some atheist is denying God's existence.
The autocorrelation function of white noise is a Dirac delta or impulse times some constant that engineers like to denote as $\frac{N_0}{2}$,  that is $R_N(\tau) = E[N(t)N(t+\tau)] =\dfrac{N_0}{2}\delta(\tau)$ where $\delta(\tau)$ denotes the Dirac delta or impulse. The two-sided power spectral density $S_N(f)$ is the Fourier transform of the autocorrelation function, and thus has value $\dfrac{N_0}{2}$ for all frequencies $f$, positive and negative. The total power is the area under the PSD, and is thus infinite. Note though that the total noise power in a bandwidth $B$ is $N_0B$.
White noise has the property that the output random process of any BIBO LTI filter with transfer function $H(f)$ (impulse response $h(t)$) and driven by white noise is a zero-mean stationary process with power spectral density $\dfrac{N_0}{2}|H(f)|^2$ and autocorrelation function $\dfrac{N_0}{2}R_h(\tau)$ where $R_h(\tau)$ is the autocorrelation function of the impulse response $h(t)$. Note hat each random variable in the output process has variance
$$\sigma^2 =  \frac{N_0}{2}R_h(0) = \frac{N_0}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty |H(f)|^2 \, \mathrm df. \tag{1}$$ Furthermore, if the white noise is Gaussian white noise, the output process is a Gaussian process and so each random variable is a zero-mean Gaussian random variable with variance as given by $(1)$.
What about random variables resulting from integrals of white noise such as $X = \int_0^T N(t)\cos(\omega_0t) \, \mathrm dt$? Well, $$\require{cancel}E[X] = E\left[\int_0^T N(t)\cos(\omega_0t) \, \mathrm dt\right] = \int_0^T \cancelto{0}{E[N(t)]}\cos(\omega_0t) \, \mathrm dt = 0$$
while
\begin{align}
E[X^2] &= \operatorname{var}(X)\\
&= E\left[\int_0^T N(t)\cos(\omega_0t)\, \mathrm dt\int_0^T N(s)\cos(\omega_0s)\, \mathrm ds\right]\\
&= \int_0^T\int_0^T E[N(t)N(s)] \cos(\omega_0t)\cos(\omega_0s)\, \mathrm dt\, \mathrm ds\\
&= \int_0^T\int_0^T   \frac{N_0}{2} \delta(t-s)\cos(\omega_0t)\cos(\omega_0s)\, \mathrm dt\, \mathrm ds\\
&= \int_0^T\cos(\omega_0s) \left[\int_0^T \frac{N_0}{2} \delta(t-s)\cos(\omega_0t)\, \mathrm dt\right]\, \mathrm ds\\
&= \frac{N_0}{2} \int_0^T\cos^2(\omega_0s)\, \mathrm ds\\
&= \frac{N_0T}{4}.
\end{align}
Thus, the quantity $q$ as defined by the OP is Gaussian random variable with mean $-\sqrt{\dfrac{E_bT}{2}}$ and standard deviation $\sqrt{\dfrac{N_0T}{4}}$ so that
$$P(q>0) = Q\left(\frac{\sqrt{\dfrac{E_bT}{2}}}{\sqrt{\dfrac{N_0T}{4}}}\right) = Q\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{2E_b}{N_0}}\right)$$
exactly as everyone says is the right formula.

Added in response to OP's comments on the original question:
If we were to assume that the white Gaussian noise process has finite power $\sigma^2$ as the OP does, meaning that the autocorrelation function is
$$R_N(\tau) = E[N(t)N(t+\tau)] = \begin{cases}\sigma^2, & \tau=0,\\
0, & \tau \neq 0,\end{cases}$$
($0$ for $\tau \neq 0$ because any reasonable model of white noise must assume zero correlation between two distinct samples), then in the integral for $\operatorname{var}(X)$ provided above, we would get
\begin{align}
E[X^2] &= \operatorname{var}(X)\\
&= \int_0^T\int_0^T E[N(t)N(s)] \cos(\omega_0t)\cos(\omega_0s)\, \mathrm dt\, \mathrm ds
\end{align}
With $E[N(t)N(s)]$ having value $0$ everywhere in the square of side $T$ except for the line $t=s$ where it has value $\sigma^2$, that double integral has value $0$.
Moral:  On dsp.SE, continuous-time white noise cannot be modeled as a process with finite power as the OP wants to do. Its autocorrelation function must be taken to be $\sigma^2\delta(t)$ and its power spectral density is thus
$S_n(f) = \sigma^2, -\infty < f < \infty$ with the total power being infinite.

The reason the variance is $N_o/2$ is because BPSK only uses the real component of the complex baseband signal,  $N_o$ is the power density  which includes both the real and imaginary components, both independent so sum in more resulting in half in the real and half in the imaginary.
I cover this in more detail here: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/54253/21048
which includes this helpful graphic:

